# Has anyone ever tried soaking grains in bourbon instead of water before smoking malt? Any advice is appreciated too

Tags: grain, bourbon, smoke

I'm going to brew an applewood smoked Märzen and upon doing some research I found some brewers have sprayed their malt with bourbon instead of water during the smoking process to keep the grain moist, this gave me an idea.

My question is: what would be the outcome if instead of the pre-soaking the grain in water prior to smoking you pre-soaked the grain in bourbon or something similar? Has anyone ever tried this or perhaps has any insight on what flavours if any would result? I'll probably try it anyway, but any point of view is appreciated.

Comment: This sounds AMAZING! Do it and report back!

Comment: If you are hot smoking, I would be really careful not to have any kind of fire/spark because the vapors would be highly flammable.  A lot of surface area means a lot of vapors.  I do a lot of crazy things, but I'm not sure I'd hot smoke bourbon soaked grain.

Comment: Have you given this a go?

Comment: I ended up soaking the grain in forty creek whiskey and slow smoking it for 4 hours. No fire issues due to there being no spark or flame in my smoker. The 2 row turned turned out pretty smokey, but it was a nice sweet smoke. It wasn't a big % of my grain bill and still the Marzen was pretty smokey. Almost too much for me, smoked it same day I brewed the beer so it was a fresh smoke. I'll be experimenting with other whiskeys and bourbons.

Comment: @craftyindian: Please, could you copy and paste your comment to be an answer and accept it as such so this post stops sitting in the Unanswered category. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have heard of it on Brewing Network, but my immediate problem would be, as @Dale mentioned, that you may end up with a boom and ash.

Seems I am also answering after you already done it with no issues! Congrats.